# Issue with Google analytics search query paramater

Tags: google-analytics

Here is the question that i want to ask you.

For ecommerce website we defined site search query parameter as "q" in Google Analytics.
The thing is when i searched for something in our search box in the website i didnt see any &q or #q parameters in the URL. It is showing something else like random charactrs instead of &q or %q.

can anyone tell me what is the reason behind it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post what is it showing then?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply on this.
Here is the URL when i searched for Laptop in site search box
"index.php?app_data=c2VhcmNoX3F1ZXJ5PUxhcHRvcCZzdG9yZV9mcm9udF9pZD0x".
Can you sort it out what does it mean, why &q or #q parameter is not appearing the URL.